# JQuery Tools Overlay Reload Parent On Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

This might be painfully easy, but I haven't found anything while searching,
I need to refresh the parent on close of the overlay. 
Any Help is much appreciated.

Thanks Jcolebrand, this works

```
$("a.help[rel]").overlay({

        effect: 'apple',
        onClose: function(){
            window.location.reload(true);
        },

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.attr('src', this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

   });
```

Comment: So you want to refresh the parent page?

Comment: So couldn't you just set the window.location property or somesuch? window.location.reload(true) perhaps?

Comment: @jcolebrand, thanks '

    $("a.help[rel]").overlay({
    
            effect: 'apple',
      onClose: function(){
       window.location.reload(true);
      },
       
      onBeforeLoad: function() {
    
                // grab wrapper element inside content
                var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
    
                // load the page specified in the trigger
                wrap.attr('src', this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
            }
    
       });'

Comment: Wow, I'm not entirely sure what that was. Try editing your question above to add that in, so it's commented and formatted like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Jcolebrand,

```
$("a.help[rel]").overlay({

        effect: 'apple',
        onClose: function(){
            window.location.reload(true);
        },

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.attr('src', this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

   });
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if it's what solved it for you :)